# How we can apply Archimedes Principle to rescue an Elephant, who has fallen into a well?

Tags: fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

Recently, an Elephant was rescued. The rescue team claimed to have used the Archimedes Principle. They said that they pumped water into the well that made the elephant to float and come to the surface. Thereafter it climbed out.
According to my understanding of AP, 
for any body of large mass to float, it must have some hollowness in it, to increase its volume. How does the Elephant has that volume in it. 
I browsed alot to study the body design of the Elephant. But, I couldn't find any adequate hollowness in the animal.
Below, I am sharing the link of the news article.
https://www.hindustantimes.com/it-s-viral/elephant-rescued-from-well-with-physics-principle-what-an-idea-says-twitter/story-VC71VxhZ9mSBPhaOqd34wO.html

Comment: Humans also float. Hollowness is not a criteria to float. Density is. If an object’s density is less than the medium it is submerged in, then it can float.

Comment: @user3518839 Yes but hollowness affects densirt. Think breast cavity (lungs)

Comment: @Gert, yes it does. But it is not a necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

Elephants are excellent swimmers, see; http://www.wildanimalpark.org/can-elephants-swim/ Even if it were heavier than the water it displaced, the water it displaced would still make it much easier to lift up with ropes or other means, as compared to trying to raise it's entire weight.